# How do I add a border around a TD element on hover without resizing

Tags: css

I'd like to add a border around TD-elements upon hovering.

```
td:hover{border: 4px solid #dddddd;}
```

This adds a border but resizes the cell.
How can I prevent the resizing?
I tried adding extra padding and deduct the padding upon hovering, but that did not give the desired result.

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 400px;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
td:hover{
  border: 4px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `outline` instead of a `border`.

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 400px;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
td:hover{
  outline: 4px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your issue -

**I have used `position` attribute of CSS for this result. Not used `outline` attribute because it will overflow your `td`.**

I have added this additional code to your snippet.

```
td {
      position: relative;
    }

td:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }

td:hover:after {
      border: 4px solid #dddddd;
    }
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 400px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

td:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

td:hover:after {
  border: 4px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```